# How to secure MVC4 area for admins from custom SQL "AdminUsers" table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.3, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-authorization

I've seen a number of examples on securing an MVC application with tokens, roleprovider and membershipprovider but none quite fit my scenario. Here's my setup..

- VS2012 linked to SQL 2008 R2 using EntityFramework 4.3 manage data.
- Project is setup in IIS for basic authentication so all staff, faculty and students with    empID can authenticate internally or externally. Some of these people are admins so they are managed in admin area.
- I've created an "Admin" area within my project that currently has no security so anyone can type domain/admin and be redirected to that area. This area contains and adminuser (CRUD), appointments (CRUD), settings (U), tools and reports functionality. The adminUser and appointments section have their own table and CRUD is working as expected.

Here's what I'm asking..
How do I validate basic authentication current user against "Admins" from my AdminUsers sql table and then only allow these folks access to my admin area?

Thanks for your time,
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not going to rely on membership or roles you could always write a custom implementation of the `AuthorizeAttribute` that checks the user against the database.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AdminOnlyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AdminOnlyAttribute()
    {
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!User not in Admin table)
        {
          throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Or something of the sort. Then of course:

```
[AdminOnly]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks brad..a few more questions. Is this a constructor? public AdminOnlyAttribute() {  }? How exactly do I use this method? How do my controllers know about [AdminOnly]? I want to redirect user to another action, like the homepage of the app and give them a viewbag of like "unauthorized" at top of page..thanks for your help

Comment: @foxtrotZulu: You can specify `filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Unauthorized" };` And you'd need to decorate the controllers that apply with `[AdminOnly]`. And I left the CTor there in case you wanted to add additional arguments to the attribute.

Comment: one little thing that helped me on the redirect from my _unauthorized view while inside my admin area. I couldnt redirect back to root Index, it would always default to domain/admin/home/index, whereas I wanted togo to domain/home/index. So the actionlink was as follows...<div class="hAccessDenied">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</div> ...Make sure you set "area" to nothing so you can zoom back to root index.